# Relative path in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, path

I am working on zend framework.
And having problem reading images path from htdocs. 
While downloading image from application with this path(/../../images/image.jpg) it works,which is in /htdocs/images/.

But while reading from application it doesn't work.

I am downloading it in htdocs because by downloading in public my application performance get slower. 

Any suggestion.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the constant `APPLICATION_PATH` defined in `index.php` which allows you to have the absolute path to your images with respect to your php files.

So in `public/index.php` there should be:

```
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));
```

imagine that your images are in `public/images/image.jpg`
you have access to anywhere in the application by

```
$image = APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/images/image.jpg';
```

But this method is to use your images by the application, not to provide access by users.

If you want to give the path of images in the application by url, utilser with view helper `baseUrl()`. 
For example:

```
$view = new Zend_View();
$baseUrl = $view->baseUrl()
$image = $baseUrl.'/images/image.jpg';
```

I hope it will help you. :)

Comment: I know how to get images from public but by doing this my application performance goes down.Beacause the number of images are more,so i need  to store in htdocs and get it from there

Comment: @user3406754 : To view your images, you can use the sprites and decrease the resolution. and you give access to the original image if the user want to see the details (fancybox example)